# What does "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: mailto:nyc@adkoa.us" signify?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to debug a click function, when I came across this error

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: mailto:nyc@adkoa.us
```

It seems to be halting a lot of debugging.

It's saying there's an unrecognized expression, within the jQuery.js file (I'm assuming it's another file that jquery is calling?).

Seen here: http://keganquimby.com/adkoa/

The real problem is that when the slider at the top is clicked, it disappears, but I have no idea why.

Comment: Code has to go in the question, you cannot link your question to an external page.

Comment: Can you post the code that causes this? We can't really do anything without it

Comment: Sounds like your file is missing some punctuation like closing quotation marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is most likely far too specific to your particular scenario. But...

1. You're loading a stylesheet as a JavaScript file. This isn't going to help much.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://keganquimby.com/adkoa/wp-content/themes/adkoa/css/flexslider.css"></script>
   ```

   Try putting this in the correct `<link href=... />` tag.
2. The error you're getting would indicate that somewhere in your JS you're trying to parse an unquoted string of `mailto...` - so it's being parsed as JavaScript, which obviously will not run when the compiler attempts to run it.

Comment: ahhhh nice!!! thank you, I just didn't know where to start looking. it was coming from a file that was passing ALL links in the header, instead of just the links in the nav.

knew this was gonna get hella down votes. oh, well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing it this way:

```
jQuery('#header').visualNav({
      link              : 'a:not([href*="mailto"])',
      targetAttr        : 'href',
      inViewClass       : 'inView',
      selectedClass     : 'selected',
      selectedAppliedTo : 'a',
      contentClass      : 'soloSection',
      contentLinks      : 'visualNav',
      bottomMargin      : 200,
      animationTime     : 800  
});
```

It seems that the script you are using (visualNav) doesn't support mailto links.

Hope this help.

Regards,

Marcelo

Comment: I just changed the selector at the top, although this is probably a better approach.